# C# XAML Universal Apps get rid of 'Mask' over TextBoxes

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, win-universal-app

I have a `TextBox` like this:

```
<TextBox Background="#2196F3" Foreground="White" Text="Hello"/>
```

But then, the background of the `TextBox` does not become '#2196F3' - it becomes a shade lighter, as Universal App `TextBox`es have this grey 'mask' above them.

`TextBox` with 'mask' - Unfocused
[image]

And to solve this, I put a grid behind the textbox and make the textbox transparent.

`TextBox` with grid - Unfocused
[image: TextBox - Unfocused]

But when I focus it,
[image]

Windows Store manages to remove the 'mask', but I don't know how...

So, how do I make the `TextBox` remain '#2196F3', even when it's focused? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I customise the 'Focused' style for the TextBox such that it does not become opaque in focused state or the mask is not there or is it even possible

As @thang2410199 said, you need to modify the template of the TextBox to implement your requirement.

For the detailed steps, please check the following information:

1.Please right click the TextBox control-->"Edit Template"-->"Edit a Copy...", then it will show you the default style of the TextBox control.

[image]

2.After that please find the following xaml in the default style of the TextBox control:

```
                   <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                 <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextChromeBlackMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeWhiteBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocusedOpacity}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
```

3.Remove/delete the following xaml inside the above Focused XAML to let the the TextBox remain '#2196F3' when the TextBox is in the Focused state:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeWhiteBrush}"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to custom the template of the TextBox. Create a new style for TextBox and apply it to your current TextBox.

`Windows Store manages to remove the 'mask', but I don't know how...`

Its because when you focus the TextBox, in the [default template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) there is a visual state for Focused state, which change UI of TextBox.

Comment: How do I customise the 'Focused' style for the TextBox such that it does not become opaque in focused state or the mask is not there or is it even possible?